# jquery: most efficient way to get and store the ids of 100+ td items?

Tags: jquery

Ok so I have about six of these calendars on page, so thats around 180 td items (1 for each date):

[image: http://i44.tinypic.com/eiwphl.jpg]

each td has an id that is equal to that day's timestamp.
the dates I want are the red ones (class of `.booked`).

So i need the fastest way to 'serialize' the ids for `td.booked` items, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get an array of the IDs using [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), like this:

```
var ids = $("td.booked").map(function() { return this.id; }).get();
```

This would result in an array like this:

```
["id1", "id2", "id3", ... ]
```

Comment: Wow Nick, you're a bloody legend!

Comment: @Nick Craver: +1 for `map` function.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly do you mean by "serialize"?

If they are being marked on the client, then the *fastest* way to collect references to them would be to collect them *as they are marked*.  Then, you already an index to them when you need it, and no retroactive query is needed.

Comment: If you did this, you'd also have to *remove* those that you unmark, meaning more iterations over your collection than just 1 on submit...there's no guarantee this is faster if you can mark *and* unmark selections, which is usually the case.

Comment: That's why more info would be needed to give the best answer.  I was assuming that the OP wanted the shortest time between first needing the collection and having it.  Obviously this time has to be taken up elsewhere.  I agree that map is the best way to collect the id's on-the-spot.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var str = '';

$(function(){
  $('td.booked').each(function(index){
     str += '&td' + index + "=" + encodeURIComponent($(this).text());
  });
});

alert(str);
```

Comment: Will $('td.booked') selector perform better than $('.booked')?

Comment: @Raja: Yes it will because it is more specific, that is it will look into only in TDs not in all elements.

Comment: if using this method, should encode the text in case it contains an &

Comment: I think it would be much easier to do `.push({ name: 'td', value: $(this).text() })` and call [`jQuery.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) afterwards if this is what you're after.